# Oracle: group values in a one row

Tags: oracle

I have different events stored in a table

```
   RESERVATION      EVENT                       DATE 
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    111             CHECK IN                2020-02-01 00:00
    111             CHECK OUT               2020-02-01 10:30
    111             DOCUMENT RECEPTION      2020-02-03 14:15
```

I need group all the data in one row, like this

```
   RESERVATION  CHECK IN            CHECK OUT           DOCUMENT RECEPTION
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    111         2020-02-01 00:00    2020-02-01 10:30    2020-02-03 14:15
```

THX

Comment: OK so what have you attempted?

Comment: i try to use Case and Union, but it looks inefficient :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a [pivot](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php):

```
select * from 
(
  select reservation, event, dt 
  from test
)
pivot( max(dt) for event in ('CHECK IN','CHECK OUT','DOCUMENT RECEPTION') )
```

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d665/1) example.

Answer (score 0):

Anotherway is to use conditional aggregation as following:

```
Select reservation,
       Max(case when event = 'CHECK IN' then dt end) as check_in_dt,
       Max(case when event = 'DOCUMENT RECEPTION' then dt end) as document_reception_dt,
       Max(case when event = 'CHECK OUT' then dt end) as check_out_dt
  From your_table
Group by reservation
```

Cheers!!